# using two diffrenet bloc inside the app does not work

Tags: flutter, bloc, navigator

i am using bloc with freezed, i am using an **AuthBloc** on **MyApp** then i need to use another bloc inside the **Product Page** .

the the user click on the **button** inside **Product Page**, **Details Page** will be opened.
but when the user click the button there is no action happened, or error.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
      create: (context) => AuthBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Router(
          routerDelegate: AppRouterDelegate(),
          backButtonDispatcher: RootBackButtonDispatcher(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Products Page:**

```
class ProductPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductPage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<ProductsBloc>(
      create: (context) => ProductsBloc(),
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Products'),
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: FittedBox(child: BlocBuilder<ProductsBloc, ProductsState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return TextButton(
                child: Text("More Details"),
                onPressed: () => BlocProvider.of<ProductsBloc>(context)
                    .add(const ProductsEvent.goToDetailsEvent()),
              );
            },
          )))),
    );
  }
}
```

**ProductBloc:**

```
class ProductsBloc extends Bloc<ProductsEvent, ProductsState> {
  ProductsBloc() : super(_Initial());

  @override
  Stream<ProductsState> mapEventToState(
    ProductsEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if(event is GoToDetailsEvent){
      yield GoToDetailsState();
    }
  }
}
```

**Product Event:**

```
@freezed
class ProductsEvent with _$ProductsEvent {
  const factory ProductsEvent.started() = _Started;
  const factory ProductsEvent.goToDetailsEvent() = GoToDetailsEvent;
}
```

**Product State:**

```
@freezed
class ProductsState with _$ProductsState {
  const factory ProductsState.initial() = _Initial;
  const factory ProductsState.goToDetailsState()=GoToDetailsState;
}
```

**Router Delegate Code:**

```
class AppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin {
  AppRouterDelegate() : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Navigator(
          key: navigatorKey,
          pages: [
            MaterialPage(
              key: ValueKey("Home"),
              child: HomePage(),
            ),
            if (state is SignInState)
              MaterialPage(
                 key: ValueKey("Auth"),
                child: AuthPage(),
              ),
            if (state is ProductState)
              MaterialPage(
                 key: ValueKey("Product"),
                child: ProductPage(),
              ),
            if (state is GoToDetailsState)
              MaterialPage(
                 key: ValueKey("Details"),
                child: DetailsPage(),
              ),
          ],
          onPopPage: (route, result) {
            if (!route.didPop(result)) return false;
            return true;
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(configuration) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd better just call 'Navigator.push()' than bloc event to change view.
Or if you want to maintain this structure, would you share 'ProductBloc' code?

Comment: You really should provide the error as well as which line it refers to.

Comment: @KuKu i updated the post, as you wanted. in addition to the router delegate code

Comment: @GazihanAlankus there is no error, the cmd does not tell me any thing onClick the button

Comment: You sent a 'ProductsEvent.goToDetailsEvent' at ProductPage but your 'BlocBuilder' in AppRouterDelegate's build method is for AuthBloc.

Comment: @KuKu you're write thanks a lot.
there is a way to build 2 blocs inside BlocBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sent a 'ProductsEvent.goToDetailsEvent' at ProductPage but your 'BlocBuilder' in AppRouterDelegate's build method is for AuthBloc.

If you want to use 2 BlocBuilder, just refer to below code.
You need to change each state's name to distinguish each bloc state.
(But I am not sure that it is best way.)

```
...
BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
    builder: (context, authState) {
        return BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
            builder: (context, productState) {
                return Navigator(
                    key: navigatorKey,
...
```

Comment: i have added MultiBlocProvider in app root included the two blocs, then i created a nested code  with if condition
if (productState is GoToDetailsState)  
MaterialPage(key: ValueKey("Details"),child: DetailsPage(), ),
But the same issue still exist, when i click the button there is no change. @Kuku

Comment: Where the MultiBlocProvider is located? In 'MyApp' class? If that, did you removed 'BlocProdier' in ProductPage? Let me know new code by updating question.

Comment: i have added an alternative answer down below instead of nested blocBuilder, hopping you check it  out :)

Answer (score 0):

this is an alternative answer instead of nested blocBuilder.

```
class AppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin {
  AppRouterDelegate() : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authState = context.watch<AuthBloc>().state;
    final productsState = context.watch<ProductsBloc>().state;
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        MaterialPage(
          key: ValueKey("Home"),
          child: HomePage(),
        ),
        if (authState is SignInState)
          MaterialPage(
            key: ValueKey("Auth"),
            child: AuthPage(),
          ),
        if (authState is ProductState)
          MaterialPage(
            key: ValueKey("Product"),
            child: ProductPage(),
          ),
        if (productsState is GoToDetailsState)
          MaterialPage(
            key: ValueKey("Details"),
            child: DetailsPage(),
          ),
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) return false;
        return true;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(configuration) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```